# Is there any workaround to a core update still showing after core update if language set to anything other than US English

Tags: updates, options, language

I build sites typically in UK English, however I typically leave them in US English because if I set **system/general/site language** to anything other than "English ( United States)" then when I do updates it always leaves one update and a message eg

> If you need to re-install version 4.2.2–en_GB, you can do so here or
>   download the package and re-install manually:

I use [Infinite WP](http://infinitewp.com/) to do my updates so this doesn't fit with my workflow, hence I leave the sites set to US English. Is there any workaround so I can get my updates all happening at the same time?